# Apache_beam[gcp] - GroupBy result to seperate folder(GCP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Input data needs to be segregated based on particular column and store in seperate folders in GCP. In below code snippet, planning to write to GCP from writeEachGroupToGCP class. Tried creating a child pipeline from this class, or write directly to gcp, all are failing. if there is any better option, please suggest

InputData: Employee data with columns (ID, Ename, HireDate, ManagerName)

```
class writeEachGroupToGCP(DoFn):
  def process(self, data,gcp_out_prefix):
    (partition, tble)=data
    #TODO: Write to GCP, gcp_out_prefix+"/Manager={}".format(partition)
    
    return data

p1 = beam.Pipeline()

(
    p1
     | beam.io.ReadFromText("indata/dept_data.txt")
     | beam.Map(lambda x: str(x).split(","))
     | beam.Map(lambda x: (x[3], x)) 
     | beam.GroupByKey()
     | beam.ParDo(writeEachGroupToGCP())
)
p1.run()
```

Comment: Hi, do you process this as batch or streaming pipeline?

Comment: What about WriteIO for Apache Beam? https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.fileio.html I have not tried with Python, but with java you can specify a function to create a bucket path you expect.